# Django modelform is not saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This is my view:

```
@login_required
def createPackage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = packageCreateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            x = p_form.cleaned_data.get('pickup_phoneNumber')
            y = p_form.cleaned_data.get('item')
            print(x,y)
            messages.success(request, f'Hi {request.user.username} you have successfully created an order with POST BOX oure customer care reperesntative will reach out to you soon ')
            return redirect('post-box-home')
        else:
            print("-----Form is not valid-----")
            
    else:
        p_form = packageCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'packages/createPackage.html', {'p_form': p_form})
```

This is the form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Package



class packageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['item', 'description', 'weight', 'quantity', 'Contained_In', 'pickup_phoneNumber', 'delivery_phoneNumber',  'pickup_address','delivery_address']
```

This is the model:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    item = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description= models.TextField()
    package_no =models.IntegerField(default=0)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    quantity= models.IntegerField(default=1)
    drop_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pickup_address= models.TextField()
    Contained_In = models.CharField(choices=CONTAINED_LIST, max_length=3, help_text='Select the package you item can be contained in', default= "")
    delivery_address= models.TextField()
    pickup_phoneNumber= PhoneNumberField(default = '')
    delivery_phoneNumber= PhoneNumberField(default = '')
    pickup_price=models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    delivery_price=models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    package_status=models.CharField(choices=PACKAGE_STATUS_LIST, max_length=3,help_text='Select a status for this pacakage', default= "")
    request_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # note = models.ManyToManyField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong the form pass the valid test but nothing is saving on the database.

Please I have also share the model, I don't know if it could be from there.

Comment: Also share `Package` model. Why you are passing `instance=request.user`?

Comment: thats because the model is having an owner field thats link to user

Comment: I only see `customer` field not `owner` there in the model.

Answer (score 2):

`Package` model has `customer` a ForeignKey field, you are passing `instance=request.user` in the `packageCreateForm` and not handing it in the constructor, i.e. in the  `__init__()` of the form, so you first do `commit=False` then save it's `customer` field, so:

```py
@login_required
def createPackage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = packageCreateForm(request.POST)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            package=p_form.save(commit=False)
            package.customer=request.user
            package.save()
            x = p_form.cleaned_data.get('pickup_phoneNumber')
            y = p_form.cleaned_data.get('item')
            print(x,y)
            messages.success(request, f'Hi {request.user.username} you have successfully created an order with POST BOX oure customer care reperesntative will reach out to you soon ')
            return redirect('post-box-home')
        else:
            print("-----Form is not valid-----")
            
    else:
        p_form = packageCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'packages/createPackage.html', {'p_form': p_form})
```

> **Note:** classes are written in `PascalCase` so you may write it as `PackageCreateForm` rather than <s>`packageCreateForm`</s>.